# Count the number of document which contains either or both terms, and the term's values must be within a range

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to count the number of document that

1. has either or both term A and term B
2. if term A or/and term B exist, the value is between a range.

I manage to write count for single term count as below and it returns correct count. However, how should I change it to include term "B" with an "OR" logic?

```
GET /propertyindex/_count
{
  "query": {
      "range": { 
        "A": {
          "gt": 1550160000, 
          "lte":1551369600}
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query with a should clause:

```
GET stackoverflow/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "A": {
              "gt": 100, 
              "lte":500
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "B": {
              "gt": 100, 
              "lte":500
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Please notice that the above query will also include the documents
>   where both A and B are present and any of the above two conditions
>   satisfies i.e. it will return document where A is greater than 100 and
>   less than equal to 500 but B is 50 vice-versa.